Piping to the cut command returns nothing
I'm using Macos with this version of Bash:
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)
I'm grepping a log file and piping the results to cut, where i'm trying to remove the first 64 chars of each line.
This works (without cut):
$ tail -f log/development.log | grep mailer 
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/part_container.rb:45:in `parse_content_type': content_type = "xls"
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/part.rb:60:in `to_mail': real_content_type = "xls"; ctype_attrs = {"charset"=>"utf-8"}
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/vendor/tmail-1.2.3/tmail/interface.rb:793:in `set_content_type': str = "xls"; sub = nil; param = {"name"=>"pmll_print_publisher_summary.xls"}
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/part_container.rb:45:in `parse_content_type': content_type = "multipart/alternative"
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/part_container.rb:45:in `parse_content_type': content_type = "xls"
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/part.rb:60:in `to_mail': real_content_type = "xls"; ctype_attrs = {"charset"=>"utf-8"}
### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/vendor/tmail-1.2.3/tmail/interface.rb:793:in `set_content_type': str = "xls"; sub = nil; param = {"name"=>"pmll_print_publisher_summary.xls"}


I want to remove the first 64 chars of each line ("### /Users/max/.asdf/installs/ruby/1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/").  I thought that if I piped the results to cut like this it would work.  But I don't get anything coming through.
$ tail -f log/development.log | grep mailer | cut -c 64-



EDIT: some commenters have suggested this is a buffering issue.  I have tried the following ways to deal with that:
$ tail -f log/development.log | unbuffer grep mailer | cut -c 65-
-bash: unbuffer: command not found

$ tail -f log/development.log | stdbuf -oL  grep mailer | cut -c 65-
<blank, as above>


$ tail -f log/development.log | stdbuf -o0  grep mailer | cut -c 65-
<blank, as above>

$ tail -f log/development.log | grep --line-buffered mailer | cut -c 65-
<blank, as above>


You're "suffering from buffering".

@MarkSetchell what do you mean?

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

@Jetchisel so, this way of unbuffering doesn't work, ie has the same blank result:
tail -f log/development.log | stdbuf -oL  grep mailer | cut -c 65-.  I don't have the unbuffer command.  Rather than posting an RTFM-style link, it would be more useful to post an answer or even a comment with a suggested fix.

I have tried grep --line-buffered mailer successfully.

@Philippe would you mind putting it in as an answer so we (and perhaps others) can discuss why it's not working for me ?

grep and cut could be something like: tail ... | awk '/mailer/ { print substr($0, 65) }'

@Jetchisel this works perfectly, thanks!  tail -f log/development.log | awk '/mailer/ { print substr($0, 67) }'.  I'm still curious to understand why the cut doesn't work though.

On my Debian/XFCE/xterm window, I run :
tail -f log/development.log | grep --line-buffered mailer | cut -c 65-

On another xterm window, I run :
echo "/actionmailer-2.2.2/lib/action_mailer/vendor/tmail-1.2.3/tmail/interface.rb" >> log/development.log

Each echo generates immediately nterface.rb in the first window.
Tested on MacOS as well, got same result as above.

I cant' see anything writing to log/development.log there, how are the two windows communicating?

The 2 windows are communicating via the file log/development.log. One is writing to that file, the other is reading from that same file. Make sure you run the echo from the same directory where you run the tail - i.e. cd to the same directory first in both windows or give an absolute path to the .log file.

@EdMorton sorry, the bit that pushes to the log file was cut off by the overflow.  Apologies.  It's not coming through, for me, in the grep line.  I've done some experiments with writing to a new file, foo.txt, and what i've found is that it does work if the file is in the same folder, but it doesn't work if it's in a different folder (the other window is writing into the correct place in either case).  That is, it works if i cd to the log folder and then tail "development.log", but it doesn't work when i tail "log/development.log" from the parent folder.

@MaxWilliams That's really strange. I'd suggest you reboot your MacOS and redo the test.
